# Easy way to restrict permissions in an elementary school computer lab?

Tags: permissions, user-accounts, group-policy, limited-access

I'm putting together an elementary school computer lab. I have nine Windows XP Pro machines that are not networked and do not have internet access (no money to do either).

I've created separate student and admin accounts, and have the students set as limited users. However, I'm interested in further restricting their permissions. I want to make it such that they cannot:

- Delete any files, even just from their own profile
- Rename any files
- Move around the icons on the desktop
- Change any display settings
- Access a usb device without a password (they bring in their own from home which are chock-full of viruses)

Oh, one last thing, they **must** be able to save word documents.

Is this even possible? I can download software, but, like I said: no internet, no server.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Windows SteadyState](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx), it was designed for just this kind of purpose.

Comment: Problem: can't get through the genuine advantage verification on computers without internet access--or can I?

I can install it just fine on my laptop and bring that into the lab, if that gets me any further.

Comment: i'd be a bit surprised if windows xp flashed up as not genuine, without any internet access. for a start, the genuine advantage update, requires internet access to download - at least it did in sp2.

Answer (score 0):

Download these files from the internet and try to setup the software on the computers later.

Windows SteadyState for Windows XP

[Direct Download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/4/af4fca6d-1202-4c30-a1bc-853e9a166695/SteadyState.msi)

or www . softwarepatch . com / windows / steadystate-dl.html