# Install Windows SteadyState without an internet connection?

Tags: windows-xp, steadystate

Based on the results of [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/140193/easy-way-to-restrict-permissions-in-an-elementary-school-computer-lab), I'm trying to install Windows SteadyState on a bunch of computers with no internet connection (but all with legitimate copies of windows XP pro). The problem is that the installer asks to be connected to the Windows Genuine Advantage server, and I can't manage that.

Is there a workaround? I can use internet at my home, but cannot have the school install and pay for a connection.

Maybe there's another program that would work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a mobile internet connection? (You know that USB thingie with a sim card). Or using a phone, connect it to the PC (with Nokia PC suite), use a mobile internet (it won't eat much for this).

If neither of these workarounds are fine with you, try contacting Microsoft for an installer which lacks this authentication.

Comment: I'll try asking them. I'm in Bhutan, so I don't really have much access to funding or equipment.

Comment: That's the only way to go then. If you can't ask anyone with a recent mobile phone and use that, nor a 3G/edge/whatever USB modem.. then yeah.